# Multi-touch mouse gestures on EeePC

Tags: opengl, multi-touch, eeepc

I have an EeePC 900 running Ubuntu Intrepid Ibex. The touchpad has some simple multi-touch gestures built in - scrolling by dragging with two fingers instead of one for example.

How would I detect multi-touch events in an OpenGL/C application?

Is the touchpad on the EeePC 900 capable of handling rotational and scaling gestures?

---

The [MPX example](http://wearables.unisa.edu.au/mpx/?q=xi2_sample) returns with `Only found one master pointer.` and the suggested `xinput --create-master "ImPS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse"` isn't recognised by xinput. So is the multi-touch scrolling behaviour built-in at a lower level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(On my Eee 1000)
xev reveals that the two-finger scroll gesture is being turned into clicks of buttons 4 and 5. The three-finger tap is just turned into button 3. I don't think the pad supports any other operations. So it looks like the pad hardware is just generating clicks as though it is a wheel mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I don't own an EeePC, however you may want to check out the [MPX](http://wearables.unisa.edu.au/mpx/) API for accessing multiple pointers in X. If you're looking for general multitouch frameworks, there are a [few](http://code.google.com/search/#q=multitouch) on Google Code.